# Как переместить форму в центр экрана?

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переместить форму в центр экрана?

Установить StartPosition в значение CenterScreen не вариант, так как нужно переместить форму уже в процессе выполнения программы после определённых действий.

```
var dataBaseWindow = Application.OpenForms[0];
dataBaseWindow.Location = ???;
```

Не могу сообразить, что необходимо написать вместо вопросительных знаков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так

```
static void MoveWindowToCanterScreen(Form form)
{
    var screen = Screen.FromControl(form);  
    form.Top = screen.Bounds.Height / 2 - form.Height / 2;
    form.Left = screen.Bounds.Width / 2 - form.Width / 2;
}
```

Пример

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        var bt = new Button() { Text = "Move To Center", Width = 200 };
        bt.Click += (sender, args) => {             
            MoveWindowToCanterScreen(this);         
        };
        this.Controls.Add(bt);
    }
}
```